# Android Room getting count of elements in an 'incoming foreign key list' in an 'embedded entity'?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, android-room-relation

I have 2 Entities, `Grade` and `Student`, `Student` is having a **foreign key** towards the class room. Embedded entity `ClassRoom` looks like this,

```
data class ClassRoom(

    @Embedded
    val level: ClassLevel

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "ClassLevel"
    )
    val students: List<Student>,

    // val strength: Int ?

)
```

What I am trying to achieve is, using `ClassRoomInstance.strength` to get the count of incoming foreign keys. Than calculating the sizes of students with `students.size`

What is the way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add all the `Entity` class files in this context. Also adding the `Dao` would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a query that returns the student count.

Consider the following POJO's, a Movie and Trailers

```
@Entity
data class Movie(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val overview: String
)
```

```
@Entity
data class Trailer(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val movieId: Int,
    val trailerPath: String
)
```

Imagine that I want to get the Movie with the trailers count

```
data class MoviesWithTrailerCount(
    @Embedded
    val movie: Movie,
    val trailerCount: Int
)
```

In the MovieDAO, I can create a query:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT M.*, COUNT(T.id) AS trailerCount FROM Movie M INNER JOIN Trailer T ON T.movieId = M.id WHERE M.id = :id")
abstract suspend fun moviesAndTrailersCount(id: Int): MoviesWithTrailerCount
```

So, basically what you want to achieve can be done using SQL queries and `@Embedded`

Comment: thank you, what if i want a list of all movies with trailer count?

Comment: You would change the return type of the moviesAndTrailersCount to a List, or Flow<List> and remove the where cause

Comment: i had to modify the query for me to make it return all movies and include the cases where count(*) returns 0, but yours was really helpfull, this is mine:

SELECT M.*, COUNT(T.id) AS trailerCount 
FROM Movie M LEFT JOIN Trailer T 
ON T.movieId = M.id 
GROUP BY M.id

Comment: I am pulling a list of items with count, so I removed the `WHERE` clause and switched to `LEFT JOIN`. But I also had to add `GROUP BY M.id` because its more than one record. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this query to your Dao, see google samples:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(column) FROM table")
int getDataCount();
```